# iterating over dictionaries in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dictionary, for-loop

So ,I have to basically create a for loop for a dictionary which contains the key values as one food item and the values being them being the producers.
That is for each item , I need to create a list of producers to be linked to it. In the excel sheet , I have the producer to be on the 1st column and the items to be on the 8th column.
producer_w_coordinates is nothing  but the list of producers that I have.

For example:
{'Apple' : ['Adam's & Co' , 'Freddie Co.']}.
Is this the right way to go about it?

```
item_producer_dict = dict()
item_list
for row_idx in range(3, wb_sheet.nrows): # Uncomment to run over whole sheet

producer = str(wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, 1).value) # 1 FOR COLUMN B
items = str(wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, 8).value) # 8 FOR COLUMN I
producer_list_local = producer.replace(', ',',').split(',')
for row_idx in item_list :
    if producer in producers_w_coordinates:
        item_producer_dict[row_idx] = list(set(producer))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to transform to a `set` and then back to a `list`.
Let the `set` do the work for you unless there is a reason you explicitly need a `list`.

With the problem you're describing, a `defaultdict` sounds like your best solution.
A `defaultdict` is a `dict` that doesn't raise a `KeyError` if we try to manipulate it before it is set. Rather it "defaults" to a type we specify. In this case we will specify a `set`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

item_producer_dict = defaultdict(set)

for row_idx in range(3, wb_sheet.nrows):

    producer = str(wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, 1).value) # 1 FOR COLUMN B
    items = str(wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, 8).value) # 8 FOR COLUMN I
    producer_list_local = producer.replace(', ',',').split(',')
    for row_idx in item_list :
        if producer in producers_w_coordinates:
            item_producer_dict[row_idx].add(producer)
```

That being said, if this is working code, this is more of a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Hey! This seems right! I will try doing this.Thankyou!

Comment: Hey! I just tried this out.The problem with my anaconda navigator is that its showing an '*' symbol while running that snippet of coder and I dont really know why thats happening.